Error while Running ./gradlew signingReport in the android folder in the project
When I run:
./gradlew signingReport

I get this error:
> Task :gradle:compileGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'D:\study\flutter\Setup\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\app_plugin_loader.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 66

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
1 actionable task: 1 executed

i tried removing firebase from dependencies , flutter clean flutter pub get but didnt work

use only gradlew signingReport this and see

This might be an issue with your java version.
First check your java version by running command in CMD
java --version
Open gradle-wrapper.properties file
Change distribution Url from
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
to
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6- all.zip

It could be different based on your java version.

can u provide me with the url of page that i can finde whats compatible to my version
